# Cref customization output

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption, cleveref

I want to add `( )` parenthesis in `subfigure` references when using `\cref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.40\linewidth}
\includegraphics{1.eps}
\caption{Sample}
\label{Fig:sama}
\end{subfigure}\phantom{aa}
\begin{subfigure}{.40\linewidth}
\includegraphics{2.eps}
\caption{Sample}
\label{Fig:samb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Sample Subfigure}
\label{Fig:sam}
\end{figure}

This is a reference \cref{Fig:sama,Fig:samb}

\end{document}
```

***OUTPUT***

[image]

***Required output:***

> This is a reference Figs. 1(a) and 1(b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the instructions

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple} % default label format is 'parens'
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

after loading the `subcaption` package. See also [How to change subcaption numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425696/5001)

---

A full MWE and associated screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple} % default is 'parens'
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{1.eps}
    \caption{Sample A}
    \label{Fig:sama}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{2.eps}
    \caption{Sample B}
    \label{Fig:samb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Sample figure with two subfigures}
\label{Fig:sam}
\end{figure}

This is a cross-reference to \cref{Fig:sama,Fig:samb}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: THank you is there any possibilities to remove the parenthesis in some occurences

Comment: @Newtolatex - I'm afraid I'm not aware of such a possibility. Moreover, given that the subfigure "numbers" are given by `(a)`, `(b)`, etc., your readers may be confused if they're cross-referenced elsewhere in the document as `a`, `b`, etc.